# How to use variables in regular expressions?

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a program to find various patterns in pi. I want to use the regular function "findall" to do this. The variable "pi" has a couple hundred thousand digits of pi stored in it.

```
regex = r"265"
z = re.findall(regex, pi)
```

This results in an error. How would I search for "265"(or any pattern) in the variable pi?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: ...findall(regex, str(pi))? Your pi variable may not be a string.

Comment: It looks like that's the problem. I generated the contents of pi using mpmath and did str(pi) before the regular function, but I guess it didn't work.

Comment: Is there a way to accurately generate hundreds of thousands of digits of pi in a variable other than mpmath?

Comment: So, if `pi` is a string, and if you don't have to use regular expression, the following will count instances of '265': `pi.count('265')`